# Update the favorit product in the previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, updates, favorites

I have to UPDATE the stock of the favorit product from the previous month. My code is liket this:

```
UPDATE Prod
SET Stock = Stock+100
FROM Prod
INNER JOIN T1 on T1.ProdID = Prod.ProdID
INNER JOIN T2 on T2.TransID = T1.TransID
WHERE DATEPART(m, Date) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
AND
```

After the "AND" I wanted to sort out the MAX(Count(T1.ProdID)*T1.NoP) - T1 is the invoice table where I have ProdID, TransID and NoP (this is the number of a bought products).
Ps. I tried and the Count won't work like this.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You allude to doing an update as well as counting something.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to multiply the productID by purchase frequency, how does that give you a usable number? If I have productID 38571 and it was bought 5 times, that would give a huge number that doesn't mean anything. Does productID mean something other than an identifier of an item?

Comment: I try to Update the stock where the number of appearances of a given product is the biggest.

Comment: Yeah, sorry a bracket slipped. I'm correcting it. I try to multiply by the number the Count gives.

Comment: You might be better off doing a JOIN on a SELECT statement that contains your values. so something like `LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(Count(T1.ProdID)*T1.NoP) - T1) AS T3 ON ...`